# Scoring an assessment within a stored procedure with different external Parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case-when

**Context:**

I am attempting to create a place for users to enter answers to a survey from clients. Scoring is different based on "XX Month" parameters. So I am bringing in the parameter and having a stored procedure calculate the score so they don't have to do it by paper.

**Question:**

What I came up with feel way bigger and messier than I feel like it can be (See Example 1). I tried putting a `CASE WHEN` statement (see Example 2 right after the declared variables, but SQL didn't like that.

I am open to any suggestions or help. I realize what I am asking, so if there is another place you know of to read up on how to do this better, I am happy doing some research (I haven't been able to find anything myself). Thank you for any help you can give.

**Example 1**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CCW_USER_HH_ASQSE2]
(
    [--In order to shorten this SQL statement just know this is where I put my external Parameters. For example :@QuestionnaireVersion VarChar(10)])
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
         @Question1Score INT,
         @Question2Score INT,
         @Question3Score INT,
         @Question4Score INT,
         @Question5Score INT,
         @Question6Score INT,
         @Question7Score INT,
         @Question8Score INT

    SET @Question1Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question1 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question1 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question1 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question1 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question1 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question1 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                        End)
    SET @Question2Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question2 = 'Often or Always' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question2 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question2 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question2 = 'Often or Always' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question2 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question2 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 0
                        End)
    SET @Question3Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question3 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question3 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question3 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question3 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question3 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question3 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                        End)
    SET @Question4Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question4 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question4 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question4 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question4 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question4 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question4 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                        End)
    SET @Question5Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question5 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question5 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question5 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question5 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question5 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question5 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                        End)
    SET @Question6Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question6 = 'Often or Always' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question6 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question6 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question6 = 'Often or Always' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question6 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question6 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 0
                        End)
    SET @Question7Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question7 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question7 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question7 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question7 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question7 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question7 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                        End)
    SET @Question8Score = (CASE
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question8 = 'Often or Always' THEN 0
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question8 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' AND @Question8 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question8 = 'Often or Always' THEN 10
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question8 = 'Sometimes' THEN 5
                            WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' AND @Question8 = 'Rarely or Never' THEN 0
                        End)
```

**Example 2**

```
...
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE
        @Question1Score INT,
        @Question2Score INT,
        @Question3Score INT,
        @Question4Score INT,
        @Question5Score INT,
        @Question6Score INT,
        @Question7Score INT,
        @Question8Score INT

CASE
   WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month' THEN SET @Question1Score =...
   WHEN @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month' THEN SET @Question1Score =...
...
```

Comment: Something like  `IF @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month'...do something` but I don't know if that really shortens your code that much. What if you created a table of the questionnaireversions, answers, and points. Then you could load the user inputs into a table, join it to the other table and sum the results?

Comment: That's not a bad idea. However, there are 9 surveys. One has 36 questions, and they scale down to the last one having 16 questions. Not all the answers result in the same point value across the board. So, while I am beginning to think I cant get away from it, I was hoping to simplify it some how. Creating another table seems to just be taking the bulk and moving it somewhere else. Is this what you were thinking, or did you have another idea in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with so far.

I created two "lookup tables" (LT__ASQSE2_ZVX and LT__ASQSE2_XVZ) and used some IF ELSE statements.

Also, there are 36 questions and 9 different "Month" surveys. So I have shortened it for readability.

```
USE [DEMO]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CCW_USER_HH_ASQSE2]
(
@QuestionnaireVersion VarChar(10),
@DocID int,
@Question1 VarChar(20),
@Question2 VarChar(20),
@Question3 VarChar(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE
    @Question1Score INT,
    @Question2Score INT,
    @Question3Score INT

    IF @QuestionnaireVersion = '60 Month'
        BEGIN
            SET @Question1Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_ZVX
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question1)
            SET @Question2Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_XVZ
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question2)
            SET @Question3Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_XVZ
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question3)
        END
    ELSE IF @QuestionnaireVersion = '48 Month'
        BEGIN
            SET @Question1Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_XVZ
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question1)
            SET @Question2Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_ZVX
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question2)
            SET @Question3Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_XVZ
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question3)
        END
    ELSE IF @QuestionnaireVersion = '36 Month'
        BEGIN
            SET @Question1Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_XVZ
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question1)
            SET @Question2Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_ZVX
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question2)
            SET @Question3Score = (SELECT SCORE
                                    FROM LTC__ASQSE2_XVZ
                                    WHERE QuestionAnswer = @Question3)
        END
END

SELECT @Question1Score AS Question1Score, @Question2Score AS Question2Score, @Question3Score AS Question3Score
```